# I need first 2 occurrences of duplicate id in the output(image attached) using sql

Tags: sql, duplicates

[image]

want first 2 occurrence of duplicate ID'S in the output, desired output in image attached.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant by "1st occurrence" because sql select queries are unorder unless you specified the order. So I'm assuming you are using alphabetical  ordering on the emails.

```
SELECT t.id, t.email, t.state_code FROM ( 

  SELECT id, email, state_code,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by id ORDER BY email desc) as cnt
  FROM testdb
  group by id, email, state_code
) as t
WHERE t.cnt <= 2
```

[db fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rFdAYHWg8D4ZDhnwePFnRQ/0)